# Is it possible to render a single game engine frame in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, game-engine

I'm looking to use the blender game engine to get my frame to a certain point, stop there and then render that single frame in cycles since cycles does a much better job of rendering for certain aspects of images.  How might I do this?

Comment: Cycles and BGE are two completely separate and independent entities aside from both running inside Blender. It might be technically be possible to extract camera position from a running game and through scripting pass it onto Blender to render another scene, but you would need some serious scripting to accomplish this and would never be able to do it from a standalone game since it would not include the Blender and Cycles binaries required for operation. You also need to set up a separate scene with proper materials to render from Cycles and it might take a considerable time to render.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to bake physics? There are ways of doing this. Otherwise, you could write a python script that stores object positions/rotations so that you can load them in blender later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  I end up running the 'render game engine' while having the 'record animation' checkbox checked under the Game dropdown.  Of course, you need to change to the 'Blender Game' rendering before this otherwise it won't appear.  Then starting the 'Game Engine' by clicking 'Start Game Engine', as it is recording, all of the keyframes are created  Once I find the frame I want that represents a good image of what I wish to render.  I move to that frame and turn it over to cycles render.  Here I can play with the materials, lighting, etc in order to get just the right image to be rendered.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to use Shift + F to move the camera in first-person game style?

Comment: I'm looking to have my final render done in Cycles Render.  I'm not sure I'm understanding how your solution would help unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You seem to be using the game engine solely for the purpose of positioning your camera. You can position your camera where desired directly from the Blender viewport by pressing Shift + F while in camera. This will enter "Fly Mode" or "First Person View mode" and and then you can render it using whatever you want, Cycles or otherwise.

Comment: I'm using the game engine for the physics so I can let the physics do their part.  Then I find a frame that fits best and then switch over to cycles.

Comment: Oh, OK, never mind then, I thought you just wanted to use first person view to place the camera.